# keyboard movement when we click on textfield in obj c

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, scroll, uitextfield

hii every one,

In my iphone app i need to scroll the page on click of textfield,actually it was working fine with xcode 3 ,on ios device 3.1.3,when i was using "UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"

but when i upgraded my xcode 3 to 4,it gave a warning saying that  UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated u cant use ,so i replaced that API by  UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey now warning is gone but its not working on ios device 3.1.3,when i click on textfield it ill try to scroll the page but it ill crash,,how can i fix this,,can any one help me,......    thanx in advance

Comment: You can use deprecated methods. They are just replaced by better versions in newer SDKs, but if you need it to work on older devices just use the deprecated methods. So, use UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (&UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey!=nil) {
    // use UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
} else {
    // use UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey         
}
```

Comment: again iam getting warning  "UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey" is deprecated

Comment: Yes, you will get the warning, that is expected. But it is working on 3.1 again, right? If it does, then this solves your problem.